# Where can I find itkScalarImageTextureCalculator

Tags: itk

I am trying to run a piece of code that includes "itkScalarImageTextureCalculator.h". However, cmake cannot find this reference, and I can't seem to find it manually neighter. I've looked for it in

- Modules/Numerics/Statistics/include
- Modules/Compatibility/V3Compatibility/include
- Modules/Compatibility/Deprecated/include

but i can't find it anywhere. A search in the itk folder also returns no results. Was this library deleted/renamed/moved somewhere else? Or maybe there is some kind of problem with my itk installation? I have successfuly used other libraries, and I only have itk installed (I mean I don't have vtk, tcl etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been renamed itkScalarImageToTextureFeaturesFilter (probably in ITK 4.0). You can see this conversion listed in the table here: [http://itk.org/Wiki/Proposals:Refactoring_Statistics_Framework_2007_Migration_Users_Guide](http://itk.org/Wiki/Proposals%3aRefactoring_Statistics_Framework_2007_Migration_Users_Guide)